# Does a dog have a larger carbon footprint than a SUV?

Tags: environment

In his song, *The Fence*, [Tim Minchin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Minchin) makes the claim that

> dogs have a larger carbon footprint than a four-wheel drive.

[YouTube video of *The Fence*](http://youtu.be/VGErC6QQdoc?t=4m43s)

Is this actually the case?

Comment: @Oddthinking -- I do not agree that this is a duplicate.  The answer to that article specifically applies to pet food and a specific book.  The answer only applies to that book and that specific methodology, not the larger question.  This question might generate broader discussion that is beyond the scope of the book in the other question.

Comment: I have re-opened it, but I am rather dubious. A (admittedly, very quick) Google suggests all the claims come back to the same article (sometimes via the QI TV show). I can't prove that Tim Minchin would, if asked, give the same article as a reference, but I strongly suspect that he would, in which case it would be a duplicate.

Comment: Tim Minchin is a comedian. His songs are comedy. The claim might be notable but a comedy song is not a good way to show it, and other samples of the claim make this a dupe. Please clarify, for a notable claim it should be easy to find many examples.

Comment: Actual source of the claim is book ["Time to Eat the Dog?: The Real Guide to Sustainable Living" by Robert & Brenda Vale](https://books.google.com/books?id=EgUrOgAACAAJ).

Comment: It seems to me that the source of the claim is the book, making this a duplicate. Let's focus our efforts in a single place. In any case: same claim implies same answer, therefore it's the same question. The duplicate source is a bit more specific, however it has a good answer, is older and has a higher score.